# Mobile Ajax Cart on topbar

Tags: javascript

Then I open website on mobile mini Cart popup open when click on it. But do not close this popup then you chroll down or click on cart icon or text.

*In header.tpl code:*

```
<div class="cart">
<span class="text-label"><?php echo $cart; ?></span> 
</div>
```

*In javascript\common.js*

```
/* Ajax Cart */
    $('#cart > .heading a').live('click', function() {
        $('#cart').addClass('active');

        $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');

        $('#cart').live('mouseleave', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
    });
```

*module\cart.tpl  In the end page code:*

```
<div class="checkout">
<!--      <a href="<?php echo $cart; ?>" class="button btn btn-outline"><?php echo $text_cart; ?></a>  -->
      <a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>" class="button btn btn-outline"><?php echo $text_checkout; ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <div class="empty"><?php echo $text_empty; ?></div>
```

were I can fix it?

On dekstop it works fine.

Comment: Because in desktop you can `mouseleave` but in mobile we don't have mouse.

Comment: What alternative would you suggest this situacion?

Comment: You can add one more button in `#cart`. And add event to this button to remove class active from `#cart`

Comment: Could you share how it should look like on my code? Please

Comment: I posted my answer. Maybe this will help you out.

Comment: Hide Button show near by cart text http://prntscr.com/j6t7m8it is posible to do on popup

Comment: look like this: http://prntscr.com/j6t8m6

Comment: You can simply add x button

Comment: I add in module/cart.tpl  

'<div class="checkout">
<!--      <a href="<?php echo $cart; ?>" class="button btn btn-outline"><?php echo $text_cart; ?></a>  -->
      <a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>" class="button btn btn-outline"><?php echo $text_checkout; ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <div class="empty"><?php echo $text_empty; ?><button class="button-hidex">Hide</button></div>'  

But it not work: http://prntscr.com/j6tgze

How it do look like Search button near by popup? http://prntscr.com/j6tg7x
@Tan Duong

Comment: You need to style it again. It is just my idea, you need to do by your own.

Comment: Ok I do style by my own. But there is one problem how to do that work (button-hide) then click on it? Now popup do not hide :/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try

HTML

```
<div class="cart">
<span class="text-label"><?php echo $cart; ?></span> 
<button class="button-hide">Hide</button>
</div>
```

CSS using to hide button in desktop

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    .button-hide {
       display: none;
     }
}
```

Jquery

```
 $('#card .button-hide').live('click', function() {
       $('#card').removeClass('active');
    });
```